# How to store the path of a media file in Cassandra when using django-cassandra-engine?

Tags: django, database, django-models, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Hey guys I am learning to implement Cassandra db with Django. In SQL db's we can store the path of a file in `FileField`, but how to do the same with Cassandra? Can anyone give some insights?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the CQL type `text` for the column and you'd be able to store any string that represents the path to a file. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the response, I thought there will be a Django way with Cassandra as well. :)